# SCCM remote control [CMRCViewer] connect on timeout

Tags: sccm, remote-control

everyone

For those of you who know about SCCM Remote know it does a pretty good job, but there are little things here and there that could be better.

In this case, I'd like to configure Config Manager to allow an incoming remote connection, if no-one responds to the connection request and it times out. Any ideas how this could be done? For the record, I'd rather not do a reghack.

[SCCM - Client Settings - Remote Tools Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKjVQ.png)

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Sadly I doubt it can be done. You can either allow the admins to always establish a session without permission, or only if the user approves and timeout is not approve in this case. Only exception is when no user is logged on afaik. The timeout option exists only for connections via remote desktop. The only workaround that comes to my mind is even more "hacky" than a normal reg key setting (although it includes one) so I wont even go into detail about it.

Comment: That wouldn't happen to be the Local Policy MOF compile route, would it?

i.e 
Configuring Configuration Manager Client Local Policy : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc146756.aspx

Comment: No, it would be something like starting cmrcviewer.exe with a script (probably autoit or autohotkey needed), and trying to figure out whether a timeout happened or the user cancelled (which is not really possible 100% because the message of a decline and timeout are the same so lots of guessing) and then going directly to the remote registry of the computer and just modifying the key for "connect without asking" before reestablishing the connection again (and afterwards setting that key to the original value). So the registry editing is not that bad imo but overall kinda super hacky

Comment: It seems that stucturing Client Settings to user security levels (i.e. 1 policy -Auto connect to users with few permissions; 2nd policy - Maintain high security for admins, execs, etc.) is as close as it gets for now.

Comment: Yeah, that's some real MacGuyver Autohotkey business right there, haha